# Preventing user from invoking shell commands in R language

Tags: r, shell, system

**Is there any form of preventing a user from calling shell commands in R, particularly through the `system()` function?**

My security concern is that I offer to my users an online R environment through RStudio Server. Once logged in, they can execute malicious instructions such as `system('cat /etc/passwd')`.

For instance, in PHP language we can restrict the usage of a group of functions by specifying them in `/etc/php.ini` configuration file:

```
disable_functions=exec,passthru,shell_exec,system,proc_open,popen
```

Comment: Can you overwrite the `system()` function so it is essentially a NOP or perhaps has the effect of logging them off? Or can you compile a version that doesn't have that function? (Would it run? I don't know. It'd be kind of like creating a bacterial mutant with Crispr.)

Comment: I will write a fuller answer when I get a chance, but I think you may be stuck, e.g. https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/236144647-Why-doesn-t-RStudio-Server-sandbox-R-sessions- ;  There are a variety of packages (RAppArmor, sandboxR) that offer sandboxes (google "R system sandbox"), but it's not clear whether these work with RStudio Server ...

Answer (score 3):

Here's one approach that seems to work:

```
myfunc <- function(...) print("GTFO")
unlockBinding("system", as.environment("package:base")) 
assign("system", myfunc, "package:base")
```

However, note that there are many other ways to invoke the command lines. Examples:

```
system2("echo", "hi")
readLines(pipe("echo hi"))
.Internal(system("echo hi", F))
```

So do not rely on obscuring a command for complete security.